# Model binding is not able to bind string array when post as JSON object

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net, model-binding

I have the following jQuery extension to serialize form as Json object

```
(function () {
    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if ((typeof (this.value) === "boolean") ||
                    (typeof (this.value) === "string" && this.value != undefined && (this.value.toLowerCase() === "true" || this.value.toLowerCase() === "false"))) {
                    o[this.name] = ((o[this.name] == "true") | (this.value == "true")) ? true : false; //Sets value to true if one of two bits is true
                }
                else {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                }
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery)
```

Then i have Html form

```
<form id="myform">
    <input name"AccountNumbers[0]" value="1111" />
    <input name"AccountNumbers[1]" value="2222" />
    // some other properties
</form>
```

Then using Ajax i am posting the form to server

```
var obj = $("#myform").serializeObject();
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            url: "/save",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData: true,
            cache: false
        })
```

The `serializeObject` method create json object as

```
{
   "AccountNumbers[0]: "1111",
   "AccountNumbers[1]: "2222"
  ....
  ....      
}
```

I am using ASP.NET Core. So on server i have Controller action method

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string[] AccountNumbers {get;set;}

        // some other properties
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody]MyModel model)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

ISSUE: On server, model's all the properties are populated except `AccountNumbers`. Somehow the model binding is not able to bind the string array.

**UPDATE 1**
as pointed out in the comments below issue was the array structure. I have changed my jQuery extension however it works for one level. But if i have hierarchy then it will not work

```
(function () {
    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            var name = this.name;
            var val = this.value;
            if (name && name.indexOf("[") > -1) {
                name = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf("["));
            }

            if (o[name]) {
                if ((typeof (val) === "boolean") ||
                    (typeof (val) === "string" && val != undefined && (val.toLowerCase() === "true" || val.toLowerCase() === "false"))) {
                    o[name] = ((o[name] == "true") | (val == "true")) ? true : false; //Sets value to true if one of two bits is true
                }
                else {
                    if (!o[name].push) {
                        o[name] = [o[name]];
                    }
                    o[name].push(val || '');
                }
            } else {
                o[name] = val || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery)
```

The extension will not work for

```
<input name="Person[0].AccountNumber[0]" value="1111" />
<input name="Person[0].AccountNumber[1]" value="2222" />
<input name="Person[1].AccountNumber[0]" value="3333" />
<input name="Person[1].AccountNumber[1]" value="4444" />
```

Comment: With a hierarchy, you could adapt your solution to recursively parse the parts. However, at this stage, it might make sense to consider a data binding engine for more complex structures. Something like Vue could fit your needs as it doesn't require much to drop into a page.

Comment: using Vue is like completely changing architecture. I need this to work on one page

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update your `AccountNumbers` property on your JSON body to be an array type. ASP.NET Core is seeing each of the indexed `AccountNumbers` properties as different properties and not part of a collection.

Something like this should work:

```
{
  AccountNumbers: ["1111", "2222"]
}
```

If this were a GET request, you could pass each item of the array as query string parameters with the same name. 
For example:

```
/save?AccountNumbers=1111&AccountNumbers=2222
```

Note: This approach will not work with JSON POST bodies as duplicate keys aren't allowed in valid JSON.

Comment: you are correct i need to change my jQuery extension to create correct array structure.